# Conjugate Complex Number In Polar Representation

Tags: complex-numbers

We have $z=x+yi$ so $\overline{z}=x-yi$ when looking in polar form we have $z=r\operatorname{cis}\theta=re^{i\theta}$

So when looking at $\overline{z}=r\operatorname{cis}-\theta=re^{-i\theta}$

So in case of multiplication we get

$$z\overline{z}=r\operatorname{cis}\theta\cdot r\operatorname{cis}(-\theta)= r^2[(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))(\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta))]= r^2[(\cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta))(\cos(\theta)-i \sin(\theta))]= r^2[\cos(\theta)^2\sin(\theta)^2]=r^2$$

and $$z\overline{z}=re^{i\theta}re^{-i\theta}= r^2[e^{i\theta}e^{-i\theta}]= r^2[e^0]=r^2$$

Which is corollary to $$z\cdot \overline{z}=(x+yi)(x-yi)=x^2+y^2=r^2$$

In case of addition we have $$z+\overline{z}=x+yi+x-yi=2x=2Re(z)$$

And in $$z+\overline{z}=r\operatorname{cis}(\theta)+r\operatorname{cis}(-\theta)=r[\operatorname{cis}(\theta)+\operatorname{cis}(-\theta)]=r[2\cos\theta]=2r\cos\theta=2x$$

1. $$z+\overline{z}=re^{i\theta}+re^{-i\theta}=r[e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}]=r[\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}]2=2r\cos\theta=2x$$

In the case of 1. we can only solve it using Euler representation of $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$ right?

Comment: Are you asking if there's another way to solve $z + \overline z$ other than  $1$? Don't you show two other ways above?

Comment: There is plus missing: $(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)$. And what is your question? Just the last one? You don't need the identity $\cos\theta=\frac12(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$. You can also write $$z+\bar z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))+r(\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta))=2r\cos(\theta).$$

Answer (score 1):

If $z=r\operatorname{cis}\theta$, where $r>0$ and $0^{\circ}\leq\theta<360^{\circ}$ then

$\overline{z}=r\operatorname{cis}(360^{\circ}-\theta)$ for $0^{\circ}<\theta<360^{\circ}$  and
$ \overline{z}=rcis0^{\circ}$ for $\theta=0^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

$$z+\bar z=r\text{ cis}(\theta)+r\text{ cis}(-\theta)=(r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta))+(r\cos(-\theta)+ir\sin(-\theta))\\=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)-ir\sin(\theta)=2r\cos(\theta)=2x.$$

---

For the same reason,
$$z-\bar z=2iy.$$